# Need help inputting variables from a .txt file

Tags: c++, input

This is my current code, everywhere I have looked online says that it should work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string infile;
    string outfile;
    int batch1;
    int temp1;
    int press1;
    double dwell1;
    int batch2;

    cout<<"Enter Input File: "<<endl;
    cin>>infile;
    cout<<endl<<"Enter Output File: "<<endl;
    cin>>outfile;
    cout<<endl;

    string line;
    ifstream myfile (infile);

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( getline (myfile,line) )
        {
            //cout << line << endl<<endl;
            myfile>>batch1>>temp1>>press1>>dwell1;
            // myfile>>batch2;
        }
        myfile.close();
        cout<<batch1<<" "<<temp1<<" "<<press1<<" "<<dwell1<<" "<<batch2;
    }
    else
        cout << "Unable to open input file";

    ofstream file;
    file.open (outfile);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        file << "Writing this to a file.\n";
        file.close();
    }
    else
        cout<<"Unable to open output file"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Right now it outputs `347 0 0 0 0`
I cannot figure out why it starts on the second line and why the next few variables are zeros.
The file I am reading from looks like this:

123         189         49           4.0

347         160         65           1.5

390         145         75           2.0

456         150         60           2.5

478         170         62           3.0

567         160         78           4.2

Thanks so much, I have been stuck here for a while now.

Comment: `getline()` consumes the first line, but it doesn't get set to anything so it is lost. Then you use streams to start reading after that, but at that point, you are on the 2nd line.

Comment: The problem in your code is in the statement `myfile>>batch1>>temp1>>press1>>dwell1;`. According to this statement you should have an integer in continuous form, but notice the spaces between 123 and 189, they are nothing but characters. To solve this you shall change it to `myfile>>batch1>>ch>>temp1>>ch>>press1>>ch>>dwell1>>"\n";` where ch is any character. This might solve your problem.

Comment: @Suyog No! That won't solve the problem. The delimiting whitespaces are aleady considered with the `istream` behavior.

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot figure out why it starts on the second line and why the next few variables are zeros

The whole line is already read in from the `getline()` function. If you're reading further values directly from `myfile`, these will be consumed from the input stream additionally.

Put `line` into a `std::istringstream` and input your variables from that one:

```
while ( getline (myfile,line) )
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    //cout << line << endl<<endl;
    iss >>batch1>>temp1>>press1>>dwell1;
   // iss>>batch2;

    cout<<batch1<<" "<<temp1<<" "<<press1<<" "<<dwell1<<" "<<batch2;
}
```

**UPDATE**
To store multiple value sets (as per input line) create a small data structure

```
struct DataRecord {
    int batch1;
    int temp1;
    int press1;
    int dwell1;
    int batch2;
};
```

and keep all input (lines) in a `std::vector<>` of such:

```
std::vector<DataRecord> records;

while ( getline (myfile,line) )
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    DataRecord record;

    iss >> record.batch1 
        >> record.temp1 
        >> record.press1 
        >> record.dwell1 
        >> record.batch2;
    records.push_back(record);
}

for(std::vector<DataRecord>::iterator it = records.begin();
    it != records.end();
    ++it)
{
    cout << it->batch1 << " "
         << it->temp1  << " "
         << it->press1 << " "
         << it->dwell1 << " "
         << it->batch2 << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Tried that, now the output is "567 0 0 0 0"

Comment: @user3447513 Put the `cout` statement inside the loop to get a grip what's going on (see my edit). There might be more flaws with your code I didn't address. But using `getline()` together with `istringstream` is the correct approach to the solution of your problem.

Comment: but now, from where does this 567 comes?? there is no such number in file from which you are reading!

Comment: Sorry I did not include the whole file, I just added it. The 567 is the last batch number. Could it be reading and re assigning each time? How would I fix this?

Comment: @user3447513 _'Could it be reading and re assigning each time?'_ Yes the variables are reassigned with each cycle of the loop. You might want to have `std::vector<int>` instead of plain `int`values, or even better a small data structure and a `std::vector<>` for this one.

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches to parse line by line.

Approaching it using getline() leads to the urge to manually parse the resulting string, either by re-creating a stream object which then can be parsed using stream operators like >> or using sscanf or whatever else could do the job.

However, since you already have an input stream (myfile), reading a line into a string and recreating an input stream from it is not necessary.

Putting it in other words, replacing

```
while ( getline (myfile,line) )
```

which reads a line and checks the end condition at once with

```
while (!myfile.eof())
```

which only checks the end condition could already do the job since you're still reading line by line using

```
myfile>>batch1>>temp1>>press1>>dwell1;
```

just that each line is composed of/defined by 4 elements.

Here's a short example using a stringstream to replace the file input:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int batch1;
    int temp1;
    int press1;
    double dwell1;

    stringstream ss;
    ss << "123 189 49 4.0\n347 160 65 1.5\n390 145 75 2.0";

    while (!ss.eof())
    {
        ss >> batch1 >> temp1 >> press1 >> dwell1;
        cout << batch1 << "|" << temp1 << "|" << press1 << "|" << dwell1 << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```